# Sony SmartWatch2 date error

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I made some watchfaces for sony smartwatch 2 and I've got many reports that the date is showing "zero" instead of real date.

as somebody there gave this report:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=53974927&postcount=49

I found that I've forgot to add this to my guide:

```
widgets:template="dd"
```

then I tryed to remove it. And it worked http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=54004169&postcount=52

but I need to make it tow digits to fit good, so I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:widgets="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="215px"
    android:layout_height="170px" >

    <com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="177px"
        android:layout_marginTop="73px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            widgets:textSize="20px"
            widgets:timeType="days_of_month_digit1" />
    </com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the watchface didn't worked at all and the watch keeps rebooting it self

So is there anyway to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works in the same way for me too. I suppose an error in SDK. I managed to resolve it using `days_of_month` instead of `days_of_month_digit2` and `days_of_month_digit1`. Of course you must prepare 31 graphic files.